# What format does a Google Data Studio DATE field expect from the connector?

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I am building a Google Data Studio connector with a field called `date`. The field's type is `YEAR_MONTH_DAY`. Now, when I return a string, for instance "2020-09-22", the field shows `null` as a result. What value should my connector provide to have Data Studio recognize it as a date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### "2020-09-22" is of type `YEAR-MONTH-DAY`, not `YEAR_MONTH_DAY`

Without knowing the specifics of the connector you are using:

- Be careful theat your provided format matches the expected one
- Read about supported [Dates and times](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6401549?hl=en) in Data Studio
- If necessary, use date formatting methods like e.g. [`TODATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7037300?hl=en)
- If the DATE field you are talking about is the absolute date as mentioned [here](https://www.optimizesmart.com/guide-to-date-and-time-data-types-in-google-data-studio/), the expected format is `YYYYMMDD`.

Comment: I should have been clearer: I am building the connector myself. `YEAR_MONTH_DAY` is what the field type is called when creating a connector in Google Scripts. Your last point is the correct answer, I found out there was an error in the way I was formatting the date.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I have had to implement a workaround for this more often lately which is to create a new field in the data source and use the TODATE() function and use that new field in my dimensions on the report.

Try a formula field like:

```
TODATE(comp_pd_end, "%Y-%m-%d", "%Y%m%d")
```

Answer (score -2):

The expected date format for the connector is YYYYMMDD, without any separator.

You can check the official documentation:
https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference?hl=en#semantictype

Comment: Note that User [ziganotschka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64114908/12892553) answer (Point #4) also specifies the `YYYYMMDD` format, stating that: "*If the DATE field you are talking about is the absolute date as mentioned [here](https://www.optimizesmart.com/guide-to-date-and-time-data-types-in-google-data-studio/), the expected format is `YYYYMMDD`*"